# data not being displayed in spring boot using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

- I am trying to implement a project in which the values are being fetched from `MySQL` and when I am trying to return it to the `HTML` page for displaying. It is not being display but it can be seen as a `list`.
- `Controller`

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/successful")
    public ModelAndView registered(Model model) {
        List<Student> student = dao.getStudents();
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(params);
        params.put("students", student);
        return new ModelAndView("index", params);
    }
```

- `index.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="student : ${students}">
            <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.dob}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.address}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script>
var data = ${students};
console.log(data);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Output that I am able to get as you can see below the `<td th:text="${student.name}"></td>` is empty.

[image]

Comment: you are passing the map having values with the name as `students` and trying to reterive values in thymleaf from `student`, correct that to `<td th:text="${students.name}"></td>`

Comment: @Rishal I have done the targer as you can see ```<tr th:each="student : ${students}">```

Comment: Any specific reason you are putting the `List Students` into `Map` ? why not use `ModelAndView modalNview = ModelAndView("index");
modalNview .getModelMap().addAttribute("students", student );`

Comment: tried but was resulting in same thing, the output was not being displayed

Comment: you are using JSP in thymleaf ? rename the file as `index.html` remove unneccesary declaration and then give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/successful")
    public String registered(Model model) {
        List<Student> students = dao.getStudents();
        model.addAttribute("students", students);
        return "index";
    }
```